# Jetpack Compose interoperability - keep view instance

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am developing an app with Jetpack Compose. In my project, I have to add a custom map view that uses a [`GLSurfaceView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView). When creating that view, it takes some time to initialize everything. Now when I navigate to another screen and back to the map screen, the setup process is performed again for the `GLSurfaceView` which leads to the animation being stuck. I know that there is [`remember`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#remember(kotlin.Function0)), but it is only helpful for recompositions, not when navigating between screens. And saving a view instance in a viewmodel seems wrong to me.

Is there any way of keeping the initialized instance of that `GLSurfaceView` during the lofetime of the app?

(My composable looks more or less like [this](https://gist.github.com/Daio-io/2d3c30bf976e04b5e2ac17699c785987#file-mapview-kt))